# Can you force PayPal Payments Standard API to show credit card fields first?

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Website Payments Standard.  Whenever the user lands on PayPal with the variables I sent, it shows a PayPal Login form and at the bottom it shows "Don't have a PayPal account? Use your credit card or bank account (where available)."

I want it to default to always ask for credit card and maybe say "Have PayPal?  Use that!".  Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to force people to use credit cards?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say if you have to have them use credit cards, you may be better-off with a "real" CC processor. It's in PayPal's best interest for people to use their system, and no the credit cards :)

Comment: I see they also have a Pro offering that I am looking into.  It just seemed this would be the simplest / cheapest way to integrate payments on the site.

Comment: By the way - do the comments imply that the answer to this question is "NO"...?  Thats all I was looking for really.

Comment: I have no idea... the comments right now imply that none of us have any idea :)

Comment: man... I sure hate it when someone tries to redirect the question with their own opinion rather than answering the question.

Comment: @RCNeil: I was just thinking the same thing. Not much help in that!

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10148918/1066234

Answer (score 22):

I've struggled with this question and found the answer following Roberts comment about using LANDINGPAGE=Billing in the ExpressCheckout API.

---

From the page:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

**LANDINGPAGE**:Type of PayPal page to display.

It is one of the following values:

- Billing – Non-PayPal account
- Login – PayPal account login

---

Additionally see:

**SOLUTIONTYPE**: Type of checkout flow. It is one of the following values:

- Sole – Buyer does not need to create a PayPal account to check out. This is referred to as PayPal Account Optional.
- Mark – Buyer must have a PayPal account to check out.

NOTE:You can pass Mark to selectively override the PayPal Account Optional setting if PayPal Account Optional is turned on in your merchant account. Passing Sole has no effect if PayPal Account Optional is turned off in your account

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've got a [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/) that would make using Express Checkout very simple for you.  Let me know if you'd like help using it.

Comment: If you're using an HTML form to post to "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", adding this hidden field to my form worked for me: <input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="Billing">

Answer (score 20):

On [a thread in the PayPal Developer Community](http://www.paypaldeveloper.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=basicpayments&message.id=28117&query.id=71300) they explain it with cookies based visits to the checkout page.

Basically if PayPal detects you being a user and spots their cookie, they will show the login form by default.

If they can't see that cookie, then they will show the credit card option first with a note that if you already have a PayPal account, to log in.

So the answer is no.

Comment: And to add to that: if you use Express Checkout, you can set LANDINGPAGE=Billing in the SetExpressCheckout API call. Additionally, Express Checkout is free and available pretty much globally, so there's no reason not to use Website Payments Standard (the HTML based variant, which does not offer this feature).

Comment: @random I've just tested with a private navigation tab, so there's no cookies, and it still shows up the Paypal account as a (big) default.

Comment: agree with Yvan above.  tried with no cookies and I must either login to Paypal or Create an Account.  Also the link above no longer works.