# Force PayPal to always request credit card information instead of login form?

Tags: html, forms, variables, paypal

We are working with paypal payments standard in our website. When users fill up their request in our site and press the paypal button "Buy Now" we submit all the variables to paypal so they can process the payment.

For those users who have never been to paypal before and they are paying through our site it works perfectly well since it prompts for the credit card information automatically.

BUT: for those users who have been in paypal before we noticed that cookies are stored in the computer, and the user is prompted to login automatically before asking for their credit card information.

We want to have paypal always ask for the credit card information and leave the login to pay using paypal as an option.

Is there any variable we can send to paypal in order to force them to directly ask for the credit card information?

So far we found these variables to auto complete the credit card fields and they work great:

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="" />  
<input type="hidden" name="last_name"value="" />   
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="" />
```

For those looking more information about PayPal Form variables here is the reference:

https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics

Comment: Contact PayPal about options such as limiting payment methods. Do *not* try to circumvent any setup or act on the users behalf outside of what PayPal authorizes. In the end, PayPal might not be the best payment processors for your needs...

Comment: You cannot even pay using your credit card w/o being logged in if that card is attached to an account. If that account has enough money in it you CANNOT use the card at all...

Comment: I reformulated the question to avoid confusions, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309421/can-you-force-paypal-payments-standard-api-to-show-credit-card-fields-first

Comment: sorry @ThiefMaster but you are completely wrong, you can always receive payments from users who do not have paypal through paypal, look into the website payments standard feature of paypal, or something more sophisticated paypal website payments pro.

Comment: The ThiefMaster was right, if a user has an account on PayPal with a credit card linked to it, even if they delete their cookies, PayPal will not allow them to make an anonymous payment with it.

Comment: Still wrong guys, you can opt to pay with your credit card without using your paypal account. remember we are talking about website payments solution

Comment: Votes to close before even trying to understand the question.  Legit question.  The power users are too quick with their trigger fingers.  I wish it took 10 votes instead of 5.  5 votes is too easily abused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Robert wrote the answer in one of the comments:
LANDINGPAGE is a parameter for Express Checkout, not for Website Payments Standard. Website Payments Standard doesn't support an equivalent to 'LANDINGPAGE'. If you want to force the credit card landing page to be displayed, you'll need to integrate PayPal Express Checkout.

So there you go, @Robert, actually that is the answer I got straight from Paypal.

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution for the html-form, it is not documented by paypal*(!):

```html
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="Login" />

or

<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="Billing" />
```

This pray the paypal login to view the required form. Have fun.

* - Not documented, but there is [some information](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/Guest-payement-is-not-available/td-p/807552?profile.language=en#M17338).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the other answers, comments, and votes to close, I think there is some confusion.

There are two legitimate options for users. Either enter payment information or login with an existing account. This can be somewhat confusing for users, who may or may not know/remember their login information. Last I checked, you do not need a PayPal account to use PayPal Standard payments (although I do believe CC# and contact info are checked against existing accounts if you don't login).

To answer the original question, I don't have first-hand experience overriding this behavior, but it may be possible.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

(See the LANDINGPAGE parameter)

> (Optional) Type of PayPal page to display. It is one of the following
>   values:
>
> Billing – Non-PayPal account Login – PayPal account login

Paypal will always lean towards encouraging existing users to login (which makes sense from a marketing/retention perspective and also from a security perspective).

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="landingpage" value="Billing" /> or <input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing" /> didn't work :(, apprently it is not possible

Comment: That's too bad. The document appears current; it might be worth an email to PayPal support to see if there is an explanation.

Comment: LANDINGPAGE is a parameter for Express Checkout, not for Website Payments Standard. Website Payments Standard doesn't support an equivalent to 'LANDINGPAGE'. If you want to force the credit card landing page to be displayed, you'll need to integrate PayPal Express Checkout.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's impossible by design. And it's not for security, in fact it's a much more cynical reason that they do it:

PayPal gets charged a small percentage of all credit card transactions, so the said *feature* is in fact a thinly veiled attempt to discourage users from using a credit card.

To top it off there is nothing you can do about it! PayPal's API does not currently have a variable which controls this behaviour available to developers.

You may want to consider a different payment tool if taking credit card payment by default is important to you, although in my opinion money is money.

Comment: As I mentioned above, Express Checkout does support this via the LANDINGPAGE parameter in the SetExpressCheckout API call.

Comment: But if the user already has that credit card number or even email address associated with a PayPal account, they will be forced to login.

Comment: Not exactly. Depending on certain scenarios, it may allow it to go through. But in principle you're right.

Answer (score -3):

Probably not. This is a PayPal security feature. No amount of cookies, sessions, or gathered information in the world is more secure than logging in AGAIN.

Comment: The idea is not to bother customers with having to log in to pay, we want them to be able to pay directly using their credit, which is possible, but paypal leaves the credit card payment as an option for those who have been to paypal before. We want to always display the credit card form and leave the login as an option

Comment: Frankly, I'd prefer to *login* to Paypal.  I never remember my credit card number, but I can easily remember my Paypal login.  And lots less typing by logging in.  But I understand that people forget their login too.