# How To Use The New PayPal Checkout Page?

Tags: paypal

I'm currently using PayPal Express Checkout.

Here's a screenshot of the checkout page I want people taken to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0UC.png

For some reason users are taken to the older looking checkout page.  I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere that let's you choose to specific for this template to be used instead of the older one.

Does anyone know if there's a variable in their API or perhaps a URL parameter that can be set to force all users to this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force to use the new layout of PayPal Checkout. It has been rolled out gradually and partially deployed, and it is random. Something like [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). You can refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289035/inconsistent-checkout-screens-for-paypal-express-checkout).