# How to set PayPal express checkout landingpage billing(debit card)

Tags: php, paypal

I would like to set paypal landingpage's part where you can enter your credit card information is open by default.

```
    <form target="_top" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TU9GTJP2JCEKJ">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout"> 
<input type="hidden" name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="Sole"> 
<input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing">
 <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"> 
    </form>
```

Required parameters are setted I have a business account, PayPal Account Optional:
ON,
name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="Sole"
name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing"

Paypal landingpage still remaining login

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your answer here. [Can you force PayPal Payments Standard API to show credit card fields first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309421/can-you-force-paypal-payments-standard-api-to-show-credit-card-fields-first)

You're using the PayPal Website Payment Standard. That variable doesn't apply to it, as it only for Express Checkout.

If you're using Express Checkout, basically, it is based on the cookies checking. If you've PayPal cookies exists in your browser, it will be default on the login menu. Else, by setting up LANDINGPAGE=Billing it should by default open up the credit card menu.

Comment: ^ correct. Standard buttons will default on the browsers cookies (ie: if they have ever logged into a paypal account then the log in page displays. Else if there is no cookie because they have never logged in, they will land on the credit card guest checkout section.) That variable will do nothing for paypal standard because that was developed for express checkout customers since express checkout originally didnt offer guest check out with credit cards.

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="Billing">`

This works as of Sep 2016

Note that the field is landing_page and not LANDINGPAGE

Please mods don't delete posts that give a working solution and more clarity to the question

Answer (score 0):

Using call from server I had to write something like this:

'intent' => 'sale',
"application_context" =>
array(
"locale" => "he-IL",
"landing_page" => "BILLING",
),
"redirect_urls" => array(
"return_url" => $return_link,
"cancel_url" => $cancel_link
),
See docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/